# Typing a question ID in the search box doesn't "work"

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, questions, search

If I type question or answer ID into the search box, I would expect that to shortcut me to that question or at least a search results page with that answer/question.

But it doesn't.

Comment: Looks like your expectations are wrong.

Comment: That's why this is a feature request instead of a bug

Comment: Personally I just expect the search box to return an arbitrary set of questions and answers that are partially related to my query. I would never expect a the results of a search to return what I *want*. That's just unreasonable.

Comment: This is not a novel idea. Many sites do this already: eBay, Amazon, Redmine, FogBugz...

Comment: Trac does that sort of thing as well: #123 takes you to ticket 123, r123 to commit 123, CamelCase to wiki page CamelCase, etc.  It is quite useful, and entering a bare number in the SO search should be a pretty good indication that the user wants to go there.

Comment: This feature works for me.

Comment: It looks like it's been implemented. Thanks SO team!

Comment: it's been implemented for MANY MANY MONTHS.

Comment: hmmm...that's weird. I tried it on two machines... I guess I'm crazy. Thanks, nonetheless!

Comment: well, it does have to be a minimum # of digits, but this is rarely a problem in actual use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

uhh.. it already does that?

https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=33155

Answer (score 1):

Type a space after the number. That usually solves it for me.

Comment: That helps but isn't quite there. In the case of SO# 338156, it takes me to a duplicate which leads me to the question I was asking for

Comment: I know this was the only way of making it work on an iPod touch. I have no idea why the space makes a difference. Other than that, I have no ideas.

Answer (score 1):

Just a point, but if you know the question ID, why don't you *type it into the address bar*?

Comment: i.e. `http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/<ID>`

Comment: Yes, that's the work around...

Comment: It's not really intended behaviour for the search box to work like that. It IS intended behaviour for the address bar to work like that.

Comment: Actually it is intended behavior.

Comment: @jjnguy: it appears to only have been implemented today; thanks!

Comment: Was implemented MONTHS AGO.