# Any link on stackoverflow where you put question number and question comes

Tags: support, questions, hyperlinks

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Typing a question ID in the search box doesn't “work”](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33155/typing-a-question-id-in-the-search-box-doesnt-work)

Today I was auditing my reputation where i was given question numbers. I was seeing question numbers which do not figure in my reputation graph for today.

Since reputation audit looks like a text file (.txt) page displayed in browser and do not provide link to questions, so i was thinking is there any link on stackoverflow where you put question number and question comes?

Comment: Please don't remove the duplicate link.